# error with inner join - table not found although it's there

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

```
SELECT * FROM "animalTbl" 
  INNER JOIN "deathTbl" 
  ON animalTbl.animalID = deathTbl.animalID;
```

this is my code, and when I run it shows a problem like this

```
 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "animaltbl"
LINE 3: ON animalTbl.animalID = deathTbl.animalID;
  ^
```

Comment: Use the same case sensitive table name or aliases to qualify columns

Comment: Don't use quoted identifiers - that will save you trouble like that

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object names in postgres are generally case **insensitive**, but using double quotes to reference them forces case-sensitivity. Assuming the `from` clause is right, you should be consistent with your notations, and use the same notation in the `on` clause as you did in the `from` and `join` clauses:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       "animalTbl" 
INNER JOIN "deathTbl" ON "animalTbl".animalID = "deathTbl".animalID;
-- Here -----------------^---------^------------^--------^
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the same case sensitive table name or aliases to qualify columns

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM "animalTbl" a
  INNER JOIN "deathTbl" d
  ON a.animalID = d.animalID
```